# How to make the objects fall in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this game, you should not collide the falling object. I have the objects falling and I have my black square, but it flashes when I run it and Im not sure how to make the code stop when the two objects collide together.
here is the code that I have so far!

```
 <html>
        <body>

<canvas id="canvasRegn" width="600" height="450"style="margin:100px;"></canvas>

            <script>




var ctx;
var imgBg;
var imgDrops;

var noOfDrops = 50;
var fallingDrops = [];


    function drawBackground(){  
        ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0); //Background
    }

    function draw() {
        drawBackground();

        for (var i=0; i< noOfDrops; i++)
        {
        ctx.drawImage (fallingDrops[i].image, fallingDrops[i].x, fallingDrops[i].y); //The rain drop

        fallingDrops[i].y += fallingDrops[i].speed; //Set the falling speed
        if (fallingDrops[i].y > 480) {  //Repeat the raindrop when it falls out of view
        fallingDrops[i].y = -25 //Account for the image size
        fallingDrops[i].x = Math.random() * 800;    //Make it appear randomly along the width    
        }

        }
    }

    function setup() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasRegn');

        if (canvas.getContext) {
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    imgBg = new Image();
           imgBg.src = "http://www.hamdancommunications.com/HComm/img/wite%20square.png";
        setInterval(draw, 36);
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfDrops; i++) {
            var fallingDr = new Object();
            fallingDr["image"] =  new Image();
        fallingDr.image.src = 'http://s18.postimg.org/o6jpmdf9x/Line1.jpg';

            fallingDr["x"] = Math.random() * 800;
            fallingDr["y"] = Math.random() * 5;
            fallingDr["speed"] = 3 + Math.random() * 5;
            fallingDrops.push(fallingDr);
            anotherGame();

            }

        }
    }

setup();

        function anotherGame(){


               var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasRegn");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", clicked);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", moved);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", released);

            var isclicked = 0;

            var square = new Object();
            square.color = "black";
            square.x = 100;
            square.y = 100;
            square.w = 50;
            square.h = 50;


            var offX = 0;
            var offY = 0;

            function draw(){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

                ctx.fillStyle = square.color;
                ctx.fillRect(square.x,square.y,square.w,square.h);
            }


            function game(){
            }

            function clicked(e){
                var x = e.offsetX;
                var y = e.offsetY;
                if(x >= square.x && x <= square.x + square.w &&
                    y >= square.y && y <= square.y + square.h){
                    isclicked = 1;
                    offX = x - square.x;
                    offY = y - square.y;
                }
                }

            function moved(e){
                if(isclicked == 1){
                    var x = e.offsetX;
                    var y = e.offsetY;
                    square.x = x - offX;
                    square.y = y - offY;
                }

                }

            function released(e){
                var x = e.offsetX;
                var y = e.offsetY;
                isclicked = 0;
            }

            var drawtimer = setInterval(draw, 1000/30);
            var gametimer = setInterval(game, 1000/10);




        }





            </script>

        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly are you having trouble with? What have you tried? Pasting your entire code and asking other people to help you code it is not really a question.

Comment: There are ready-to-use 2D game engines available which solve your problem and much more. Check out [pixi.js](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js) for example.